# Safari memo keeps popping up on iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone, safari

Every so often when I double click the home button on my iPhone6 (to switch between apps or close apps) I see a memo along the bottom saying something like **`Safari – From "Your Mac Mini"`**. My Mac Mini is my desktop computer an my iPhone6 is my mobile device, *but* I don't use or open Safari on either of them. I've clicked the memo before and it's usually just a random site I've recently visited on *Chrome*.

1. What are these memos for/about?
2. How do I stop them from happening?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are (perhaps inadvertently) using **Handoff** between your iPhone and your Mac Mini. This [Support Page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25169?locale=en_US) at Apple describes the Handoff setup process.

*Extracted from the Support Page:*

**Turn Handoff on or off**

Note: If you don’t see a Handoff option on your device, it doesn’t work with Handoff.

- On your Mac: Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click General,
  then select “Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices”
  (below “Recent items”). To turn it off, deselect the option.
- On iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch: Go to Settings > General > Handoff,
  then tap to turn on Handoff. To turn it off, tap the option.

Comment: Or for short he can turn off bluetooth when near his Mac, in case he wants the feature in the future.